# regex if (text contain this text) match this

Tags: regex

I have these two sentence

> TAGGING ODP:-7.160792, 113.496069
>
> TAGGING pel:-7.160792, 113.496069

I want to match -7.160792 part only if the full sentence contain "odp" in it.

I tried the following (?(?=odp)-\d+.\d+) but it doesn't work, i don't know why.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `odp.*(-\d+\.\d+)`, see https://regex101.com/r/vol3d4/1

Comment: You have to understand that the zero-width assertion `(?=odp)` is tested at the same position in the string than `-\d+...`. Consequence, you wrote an always false pattern. (a position can't be an `o` and a `-` at the same time). As an aside, to figure a litteral dot you have to escape it: `\.`

Comment: @namaasliku Did any of the answers work out?

Answer (score 1):

`(?(?=odp)-\d+\.\d+)` won't work because `(?=odp)` is a positive lookahead that imposes a constraint on the pattern on the right, `-\d+\.\d+`. Namely, it requires `odp` string to occur exactly at the same location where `-` and a  number are expected.

Use

```
(?<=ODP:)-\d+\.\d+
ODP:(-\d+\.\d+)
```

If lookbehinds are supported, the first variant is more viable.
Otherwise, another option with capturing groups is good to use.

And if `odp` can appear anywhere, even after the number:

```js
(?i)^(?=.*odp).*(-\d+\.\d+)
```

This will capture the value into a group.

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?i)                     set flags for this block (case-
                           insensitive) (with ^ and $ matching
                           normally) (with . not matching \n)
                           (matching whitespace and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    odp                      'odp'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: *"If lookbehinds are supported, the first variant is more viable."*: not totally agree with that: 1) with a lookbehind, you have to reach a position in the string more far from the left to make it succeed. 2) a pattern starting with a literal string is by most of the regex engines optimised (positions where the literal part is found before with a fast algorithm, and the pattern is tested only at these positions). You can only feel a real difference with large strings, and the *"lookbehind way"* gives the result without capturing groups, but it's important to keep this mechanism in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/CdAtMQ/1), `(?i)(?<=odp:)[^,]*`.

**Explanation:**

- `(?i)`: Case-insenstitive flag
- `(?<=odp:)`: Positive lookbehind for `odp:`
- `[^,]*`: Anything but `,`

If you want the match to be restricted to numbers only, you can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/174yaj/1), `(?i)(?<=odp:)(?:-\d+.\d+)`

**Explanation:**

- `(?i)`: Case-insenstitive flag
- `(?<=odp:)`: Positive lookbehind for `odp:`
- `(?:`: Start non capturing group

  - `-`: Literal, `-`
  - `\d+`: 1+ digit(s)
  - `.\d+`: `.` followed by 1+ digit(s)
- `)`: End non capturing group

If the sign can be either `+` or `-`, you can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/yF7SrY/1), `(?i)(?<=odp:)(?:[+-]\d+.\d+)`

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `(?(?=odp)\-\d+\.\d+)` is using a conditional `(?` stating in the if clause:

> If what is directly to the right from the current position is `odp`,
> then match `-\d+.\d+`

That can not match.

What you also could do is match `odp` followed by any char other than a digit using `\D*` and capture the digit part in a group.

```
\bodp\b\D*(-\d+\.\d+)\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bodp\b` match `odp` between word boundaries to prevent a partial match
- `\D*` Optionally match any char other than a digit
- `(-\d+\.\d+)` Capture `-` and 1+ digits with a decimal part in group 1
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FOBSKu/1)

Comment: Very nice different approach!

Answer (score 0):

> (?<=ODP:)(-\d+.\d+)

You can try using the negative look behind.
This should solve for the code you ve provided.